# ApiController is returning a double-escaped string for a CSV string

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I'm working on creating a CSV report in an asynchronous MQ framework.

I have an endpoint set up that returns the CSV results accurately, i.e:

`Column 1, Column2, Column 3\r\nValue 1, Value 2, Value 3`

However, once this message is serialized and sent as a response, every result is double-escaped, i.e.

`\"Column 1, Column 2, Column 3\\r\\nValue 1, Value 2, Value 3\"`

... which makes the result parse with literal quotes and newline characters, which is obviously not a valid format for a CSV.

I've tried `string.Trim('"')` and `Regex.Unescape()` on the return value before returning `ApiController.Ok(value)`, but it's the serialization in the `OK` method itself that's escaping the chars. I can't unescape them on the retrieving side, because the framework handles HTML and PDFs as well and has to be agnostic to the format of the returned string -- plus, this endpoint will be used in more places and should return an unescaped string.

Any ideas on how to prevent this?

Comment: Try to pass in base64 format.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an attribute on your controller method: [Produces("text/plain")]

Answer (score 0):

So, this was happening because the API controller was trying to serialize the string like it were a JSON object.

One way around it was just to return it as a Stream, using a StreamContent in a HttpResponseMessage:

```
        string content = GetCsvStuffFromSomewhere();

        var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content));

        var response = new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Content = new StreamContent(stream)
        };

        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv");

        return response;
```